# compare dates and assign to each variable

Tags: powershell, compare

I have 2 excel files like below with timestamp (`YYYYMMdd_HHmmss`) in the directory.
There are 2 excel files in the directory. I will extract timestamp from filename in the directory and then compare two dates and finally assign variable to each.

I want to assign to `$Start` variable as `report-capacity-server01.contoso.com-20191010_171044.xlsx.`

I want to assign to `$End` variable as `report-capacity-server01.contoso.com-20191108_130454.xlsx.`

Comment: And what is your question? Do you want to know how to get the timestamp?

Comment: First of all There are 2 excel files in the directory. I will extract timestamp from filename in the directory and then compare two dates and finally assign variable to each.

Comment: In this case, please edit your question with this description for clarification.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what the files in the directory are named.. Are the names just the timestamps like `20191010_171044.xlsx` or is that timestamp part of the names? Can you give an example?

Comment: No names just the timestamps like 20191010_171044.xlsx. e.g report-capacity-server01.contoso.com-20191108_130454.xlsx like this.  I will extract timestamp from filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *full file names* sorted in chronological order by embedded timestamp (with possibly varying name prefixes), pass a timestamp-extraction expression as a sort criterion.

```sh
$Start, $End = (Get-ChildItem *.xlsx |
                 Sort-Object { ($_.Name -split '[-.]')[-2] }).FullName
```

- `Get-ChildItem *.xlsx` gets file-info objects for all files with extension `.xlsx` in the current directory (`[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances).
- `Sort-Object` receives a script block (`{ ... }`) as a criterion that extracts the timestamp from each input file's name (`$_.Name`) by splitting it by `-` and `.` characters and extracting the second-to-last (`[-2]`) resulting token.
- `(...).FullName` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to extract the full names (paths) of the sorted file-info objects.
- `$Start, $End = ...` is a destructuring assignment that assigns the 2 (chronologically sorted) full file names to individual variables. Note that if there were more than 2 files, `$End` would receive *all remaining* files, as an array.

As an aside:

Given the format of your timestamp strings, you can use them as-is for comparison, because *lexical* comparison will be equivalent to chronological comparison.

If you wanted to convert the timestamp strings to proper .NET `[datetime]` instances, do the following:

```sh
$timeStamps = Get-ChildItem *.xlsx | ForEach-Object { 
  [datetime]::ParseExact(($_.Name -split '[-.]')[-2], 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss', $null) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract the timestamp from your files, you can use `-split "-"`.

This will give you an array of strings divided after each delimiter.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path ./Path-to-files
$timestamp = $files.BaseName -split "-"
```

The `$timestamp` variable contains now an array of strings from the two files. With Index operations you can select the timestamp and do your comparison. Instead of splitting all files in your `$files` variable you can also of course loop through each file and assign the timestamp directly to variable.